# Grails one-to-one query options

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm

I am new to grails and implementing one-to-one relationship in grails and trying to query on tables and not sure on how to represent one-to-one relationship in domain classes and query the results.

I have two tables

```
car(car_id number primary key,name varchar2(255))
engine(eng_id number primary key,name varchar2(255),car_id number (foreign key to car_id))
```

**Domain Classes:**

```
class Car {
   ..
  static hasOne = [engine: Engine]
}


class Engine {
   Car car
   static belongsTo = [car : Car]
}
```

is the above one-to-ne relationship in domain class correct??

i need to query to get all the cars which have engines,should i use criteria query api or use HQL??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this already? I'm also encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Engine {
   //Car car 
   static belongsTo = [car : Car]
}
```

Just delete `Car car` and all be correct. For now u have 2 links to class Car in Engine

Answer (score 0):

For a true one-to-one relationship use the hasOne property on the owning side e.g. Car:

```
class Car {
   ..
  static hasOne = [engine: Engine]
}


class Engine {
   Car car

   static constraints = [
      car unique: true
}
```

A good practice is to add a unique constrain on one side of the relationship.  Click [here](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne) to read the documentation.